# Base64 strings in URL

Tags: safari, mail.app, email, url

I'm having a problem with Base64 strings in URLs in El Capitan.

I'm sending notifications from a web platform to its users. Those emails are **plain text** and contain links to messages.

I have tried the following links

http://localhost#VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJvcmluZyBleGFtcGxlIHRlc3Qu

http://localhost?e=VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJvcmluZyBleGFtcGxlIHRlc3Qu

However when someone clicks on a link in Apple Mail then Safari opens the links with the Base64 code converted to lowercase. I don't get why this is happening. It seams like a big bug to me. Has anyone found an easy workouround?

The only solution I found so far was to use Base32 but that just increases the length of the URLs. Another possible might be to use HTML emails but that would mean quite a bit of extra work which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Isn't the ? only valid after a page?  That is, without a "/", Mail treats it all as the host name which is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly put a slash "/" after the host name, ie

http://localhost/?e=VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJvcmluZyBleGFtcGxlIHRlc3Qu

Without the trailing / character after localhost, Mail treats the entire url as a hostname, which is case-insensitive.

Comment: Maybe you could mention that this works as well: http://localhost/#VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJvcmluZyBleGFtcGxlIHRlc3Qu

Comment: Fixed my answer. I wasn't sure if it would work without the filename; but good to know.